# Creating arbitrary object hierarchies at a minimum effort?

Tags: php, object

My `Chart` class actually allows me to create simple properties (of type `string`, `boolean` and so on) as well as nested `object` properties calling the magic `__call` method this way:

```
$chart = new Chart();
$chart->simple = 'Hello';
$chart->newComplex();

var_dump($chart);
```

Output:

```
object(Chart)[1]
  public 'simple' => string 'Hello' (length=5)
  public 'complex' => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
```

I'd like to add the ability to create also nested `object` properties as **children of other properties** (not children of chart itself) in a way like this:

```
$chart->newComplex2($chart->newComplex1());
```

**Question** is: how to use `$args` parameter and modify `__call()` to accomplish this?

```
class Chart
{

    public function __call($name, $args)
    {

        $type  = substr($name, 0, 3);
        $field = lcfirst(substr($name, strlen($type)));

        switch($type)
        {
            case 'get': return isset($this->$field) ? $this->$field : null;
            case 'new': return $this->$field = new stdClass();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: As a suggestion, first code non-magic functions that provide the functionality you're looking for and that accept either an `$args` array or that create it from `func_get_args`. You can later on still add the magic interface. In your code example, `$args[0]` is the first argument passed in case you want to know.

Comment: You should not mix collaborator and creator graphs. Your objects should have single responsibility. Allowing them create objects is one responsibility. Isolate that into factories and builder patterns.

Comment: @Gordon thanks for the tip. The chart is a simple data container object. The actual data (that is, chart series) is created elsewhere and merged with the chart in a builder (pattern) class. So i think we have single responsibility pattern respected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution by myself. The trick is to pass the parent property to `__call`. Here is the code:

```
public function __call($name, $args)
{

    $type  = substr($name, 0, 3);
    $field = lcfirst(substr($name, strlen($type)));

    switch($type)
    {
        case 'get':
            return isset($this->$field) ? $this->$field : null;
        case 'new':
            return (isset($args[0]) ? $args[0]->$field = new stdClass()
                : $this->$field = new stdClass());
        default: return $this->$name();
    }

}
```